# Javascript web browser based tool to extract local files from gzip (tgz)

Tags: javascript, compression, gzip, local-files

As part of a bigger log file analysis tool that I want to write in Javascript I need to extract text files (log files) from a tgz archive that are on the local hard drive.

I have a html page with a drag n drop field which provides the file in JS. I understood there is a [decompression API](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/compression-streams-api/) in modern web browsers that I can use to decompress the gzip portion. My problem is: I cannot use the pipeThrough function on a file. What is the most efficient way to do what I want to do?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the FileReader API yet? [This is an example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_API/Using_files_from_web_applications#example_showing_thumbnails_of_user-selected_images) of how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it helps to write down the problem to solve it yourself :)

```
const decompressedReadableStream = file.stream().pipeThrough(new DecompressionStream('gzip'));
```

did the trick.

Comment: That would only get you partway there. You'd also need to extract the log files from the resulting tar file.